# ConstraintLayout: Why does the height of a view affect its children?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am building an app in Android Studio and have a problem and I do not know why it happens and how to solve it. This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="#f4f4f4"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:shadowColor="#000000"
android:text="@string/title"
android:textColor="#eadca6"
android:textSize="60sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="342dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
android:background="#eadca6"
android:text="@string/all_quotes"
android:textAllCaps="false"
android:textSize="20sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="342dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
android:background="#eadca6"
android:text="@string/favorite_quotes"
android:textAllCaps="false"
android:textSize="20sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, if you run the code like this, the title will be cut off in half. But the 2 buttons will have a normal size. If I use wrap_content on the textview, the TextView will be displayed normally but the buttons height will also only be as big as the text inside (like inherit the wrap content), even if I don't write wrap_content in the buttons field. The LayoutEditor tells me everything is fine, but when I run the app, those design "errors" happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know what is wrong with your code so I will start with some explanation before writing code:

**TL;DR:**

Don't use fixed size on your views, you can use `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.xx"` with 
    `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.yy"` and [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html).

---

### Full answer

> **Different phones got different screen size**, in your layout, you are using fixed size on your views (fixed size is `android:layout_marginTop="144dp"` for example) and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen) will not look good on another screen (your actual phone), and this is why you are getting design "errors".

You cant guarantee full layout responsability when using `wrap_content` as well, for example, if you will take a very large image and put it on your views it wont look the same on different devices.

---

If you already using `constraintLayout` here are some tools that can help you achieve a responsive layout that will fit in size to all screen sizes.

For example, **look at this layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#f4f4f4"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:text="title"
    android:textColor="#eadca6"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#eadca6"
    android:text="all_quotes"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#eadca6"
    android:text="favorite_quotes"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**This layout will look like this:**

[image]

---

### What I did in this layout:

I got rid of every single fixed size on my views and gave them fixed size like, something like this on the view:

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15" 
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
```

This view will be equal to 15% of the screen height and 90% of its width in size, it will be responsive for different layouts.

I managed the position of the views by using [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html), for example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />
```

This guideline will be placed at the top 20% of the screen.

**Something extra** - you can use [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) / 
[sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) if you want to scale the size of your views (In your case I would use ssp library to scale your text size on your views).

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask how to learn this as a beginner? Like, any tips you got for me?

Comment: Start by creating a layouts, follow [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) page, and ask more question on stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

I added some modification in your code and added a screenshot for this code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f4f4f4"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:text="title"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#eadca6"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="342dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:background="#eadca6"
    android:text="all_quotes"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:background="#eadca6"
    android:text="favqussdi"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

[image]

as you can see i change the following:

1. `android:layout_height change` value into `wrap_content`;
2. `android:layout_width change` value into `match_parent`;
3. added `android:paddingTop="10dp"` and `android:paddingBottom="10dp"` in buttons;
4. modify `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginRight`;

remove some redundant codes and also avoid adding static number as possible. Hope i help you in small way ^^

Comment: +1 for me, **but** your answer does not make the layout responsive. You can check my answer to find out how.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code in your xml. This way buttons and text will look normal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="#f4f4f4"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="#eadca6"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/group"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="342dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#eadca6"
        android:text="@string/all_quotes"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/group" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="342dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#eadca6"
        android:text="@string/favorite_quotes"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/group"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button,button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But I need to why my code is not working and why your solution works.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because  layout_marginTop and layout_marginBottom of TextView and Buttons are too large. Therefore, the content doesn't fit on the screen and the contents of TextView and Buttons is cropped. For example, If you use android:layout_marginTop="120dp" for the TextView - content will not be cropped.

Comment: Usually when you create a layout, you set the size of the items that you know (for TextView width and height is wrap_content, for Button - static height and width), all other things should be as flexible as possible (setting so many static margins is bad practice).